# JDK 11 import root ca certificates into keystore

Tags: azul-zulu

How do I import certs into keystore in Azul Zulu JDK 11.

Where is the default keystore used by keytool

Answer (score 26):

`/lib/security/cacerts`

Took me a while to find it, but found the answer here: [OpenJDK 10 Now Includes Root CA Certificates](https://dzone.com/articles/openjdk-10-now-includes-root-ca-certificates).

Comment: Link does not work.  :^(

Comment: @PauloMerson, you are right, the link doesn't work any more, but:
1. The answer to the question is given in the answer.
2. I hope you aren't using JDK 11 any more.
3. Googling "openjdk 10 now includes root ca certificates" will find numerous copies of the original blog.

Comment: Thanks @Yaytay. My *implicit* suggestion was for the author of the answer to Edit the answer and update the link.

Answer (score 19):

From running Azul's Alpine OpenJDK11 container, `FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11`, the cacerts file is located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-zulu11/jre/lib/security/`.

But, to import new certs into it, you only need to specify the -cacerts switch and the command takes care of the rest.

Below is an example of a command I used in a recent Dockerfile:

```
keytool -importcert -file <my-crt-file-location> -cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias <my-alias>
```

Answer (score 9):

Path of java 11 trust store is *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\lib\security\cacerts*

To import cert in windows use below command.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\keytool" -importcert -file C:\Polarion\bundled\apache\conf\certificate.crt -alias labs.polarion.com -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\lib\security\jssecacerts" -storepass changeit
```

For more info visit, Click [here](https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/content/polarion/19.1/help/en_US/polarion_windows_installation/manually_updating_third_party_software/import_a_certificate_to_the_java_keystore.html)

Answer (score 7):

**For MAC and LINUX openJDK11**

first find the jdk location

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

**since keytool and cacerts located in different folder we have to specify the path**

go to keytool folder
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/security

```
Sudo keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias aliasName -file  /Users/lilojoseph/Desktop/dev.ssk.cer  -keystore  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

for checking if certificate is added run below command on same folder

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -alias aliasName
```

Comment: Worked with openjdk8 too!

Answer (score 1):

for

> adoptopenjdk/openjdk11@sha256:1cf34e59b4f6209c8513a1681a688bf8a90bf433993aa5b3914dcfdb100e9393

, the location for cacerts is:

> /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 0):

I installed Azul Zulu Java 8 and Java 11 through [`SDKMan`](https://sdkman.io/).

The `cacerts` file for my instances were as follows:

**Java 11**

```
~/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.14-zulu/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security
```

**Java 8**

*Notice the extra `jre/` folder*

```
~/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.322-zulu/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
```