# Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin, java2wsdl

Currently, we are using the java version **Zulu 8.42.0.23-CA-win64** while updating the java version to zulu8.64.0.19-ca-jdk8.0.345-win_x64 we are facing the below error.

We are facing an issue in executing the goal for the **CXF:cxf-codegen-plugin .**

```
**Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project siemops: Execution generate-sources of goal**
**org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java failed:** org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition file:/C:/SIEMOPS/repos/SIEMOPS_DEV/workspace/siemops/src/main/jaxws/SDPSiemopsService.wsdl: WSDLException
(at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
'https://siemops-test.siemens-energy.com/SDPService_DEV/SDPSiemopsService.svc?xsd=xsd5'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to
requested target -\> \[Help 1\]
Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project siemops: Execution generate-sources of goal
org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition
file:/C:/SIEMOPS/repos/SIEMOPS_DEV/workspace/siemops/src/main/jaxws/SDPSiemopsService.wsdl: WSDLException
(at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
'https://siemops-test.siemens-energy.com/SDPService_DEV/SDPSiemopsService.svc?xsd=xsd5'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to
requested target -\> \[Help 1\]
pom.xml
```

Java version : 8
CXF version : <cxf.version>3.2.1</cxf.version>

In case anyone faced the same issue any kind of help is appreciated.

We tried updating cxf version from 3.2.1 to 3.4.5 and also use the same with the java verison zulu8.56.0.21-ca-jdk8.0.302-win_x64.

Comment: *unable to find valid certification path to
requested target* looks like a certificate isse

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the certificate from https://siemops-test.siemens-energy.com and add it to the `cacerts` keystore of the JDK.

Follow this post [JDK 11 import root ca certificates into keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727161/jdk-11-import-root-ca-certificates-into-keystore) to see how to import it using the keytool.